# why pymongo/motor framework update_many method update fields value with the aggregate dict as nested document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, tornado-motor

the following scripts can be execute correctly in mongosh, but when execute with motor it will update fields to nested document.

```py
origin_children_ancestors = [ObjectId("65acdb2f025de11c4b6f4fa8"),ObjectId("65ad037edbe9cca114dcaf38")]
new_children_ancestors = [ObjectId("65acdb2f025de11c4b6f4fa8"),ObjectId("65ad037edbe9cca114dcaf38"), ObjectId(""65ae10c1652cea51d101c0c1"")]

await db.categories.update_many({
    f"ancestors.{i}": val for i, val in enumerate(origin_children_ancestors)
}, {
    "$set": {
        "ancestors": {
            "$concatArrays": [
                new_children_ancestors,
                {"$slice": ["$ancestors", len(origin_children_ancestors), {"$size": "$ancestors"}]}
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

in mongosh the scripts updated the "ancestors" correctly, but with pymongo/motor framework, the "ancestors" is updated as:

```js
"$concatArrays": [
  [ObjectId("65acdb2f025de11c4b6f4fa8"),ObjectId("65ad037edbe9cca114dcaf38"), ObjectId(""65ae10c1652cea51d101c0c1"")],
  {"$slice": ["$ancestors", 2, {"$size": "$ancestors"}]}
]
```